# CSS precedence issue with bootstrap and jquery ui

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a website using both bootstrap (v3) and jquery ui (v1.11.4). Generally this is fine, but occasionally when I use a jquery widget (e.g. the tab widget) the css for the widget takes precedence over the bootstrap css. For example:

[image]

Does anyone have any tips to help resolve this? I don't want the jquery css overriding the bootstrap css if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to load your `bootstrap.min.css` after the `jqueryui.min.js` file. *(dirty hack)*

Also note that Bootstrap has syntax for making tabs just like that. You might want to use that instead. This is a better approach since it can possibly eliminate the need for JQuery UI, if it's only been used for those tabs.

```js
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

There is also a third approach that you can take, that involves manually overriding the CSS using JS function.

also there is [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

```
a {
  color: #2780e3 !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the jQuery css from overriding the Bootstrap css in cases like this. The jQuery css is clearly using a more specific selector that will win every time, regardless of what order css files are loaded in.

However, you can override the jQuery css. In this case, assuming that you wanted to keep the default Bootstrap link color (#2780c3), you would create the following rule in your own css file, and make sure that your css file is the last one loaded into your page:

```
.ui-widget-content a {
  color: #2780c3;
}
```

Each time you encounter a case where the jQuery css is overriding the Bootstrap css with a more specific selector, you simply create a css rule identical to the overriding jQuery css rule within your own stylesheet and change the property values back to the Bootstrap css default values.

The issue you are encountering has to do with css specificity. Though it was written some time ago, the following article does a good job of explaining the concept: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/